# using tfds for using my custom dataset with tensorflow fails

Tags: python, tensorflow, command-line, dataset, tensorflow-datasets

according to the tutorial at this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/add_dataset) I want to create my custom dataset and use it with tensorflow.

I have installed the `tfds` command and when I entering `tfds new my_dataset` command, I will encounter to this error :

```
tfds new my_dataset
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/simclr/bin/tfds", line 5, in <module>
    from tensorflow_datasets.scripts.cli.main import launch_cli
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/simclr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/scripts/cli/main.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow_datasets.scripts.cli import build
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/simclr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/scripts/cli/build.py", line 275, in <module>
    def _search_script_path(ds_to_build: str) -> Optional[tfds.core.ReadOnlyPath]:
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_datasets.core' has no attribute 'ReadOnlyPath'
```

I changed the access level to `rwx`, and again the error raise.
I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem solved in tensorflow V2. so use tensorflow V2 or higher versions.